# Install my ATI graphics card in Parallels

Tags: imac, graphics, parallels-desktop, gpu

I installed parallels 11 on my iMac and installed windows on it. Then I'm trying to install my ATI card on windows so I can install the Catalyst manager as I want to disable the anti-aliasing option as shown [here](https://developer.blender.org/T32548) and [here](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?266145-Mouse-selection-not-working-in-Object-Mode-in-Blender-2-61-onwards), and to do so I need to have the Catalyst control centre installed. So I want to have the Catalyst control centre installed, Any suggestions please?

This is my iMac display details:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you'll get a graphics driver to install in Parallels, as it's using Parallels own driver. Even if you did, it would only disable AA in Windows, not in the Mac.
You might have a better chance in Boot Camp, as at least you can install the drivers to that.

Alternatively, did you try just disabling font smoothing in System Prefs > General ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would it work if I installed Vmare fusion instead of parallels?